# Организация передачи потокового видео с веб-камеры на C# (mono)

Tags: c#, linux, .net, mono

Задача: между двумя локальными машинами под управлением linux внутри локальной TCP/IP сети 
необходимо организовать видео-трансляцию используя возможности C# фреймворка Mono.

Для захвата видео можно использовать библиотеку OpenCV.

Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Это нужно сделать? Вопрос-то в чем ?)

Comment: Какой интерфейс доступа у камеры?

Comment: OpenCV вместе с Mono вряд ли пойдет под Linux. Попробуйте Emgu CV.

Comment: @uzumaxy обратите внимание на то, когда был задан вопрос. Боюсь, для его автора он давным-давно не актуален

Comment: @DreamChild, но ведь:
> изменен 1 час назад

Comment: @uzumaxy каюсь, не заметил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для .net существует отличная библиотека компьютерного зрения AForge, в которой, кроме всего прочего, есть работа с web-камерами. Кстати, эта библиотека - не обертка над OpenCV. Как эта библиотека работает с Mono, не могу подсказать, к сожалению.

http://www.aforgenet.com/